# How to assign json result to jsp datepickers in struts 2?

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-json-plugin

I am calling an Action, it returns json as a result in JSP page. My problem is, how to set this json result to my datepickers name varaible. My code is like that.

```
<s:url id="datePickerUrl" action="jsonReloadDatePickerAction" />
<sj:div href="%{datePickerUrl}">
     <sj:datepicker id="idStartDate" name="startDate" displayFormat="dd-mm-yy" showOn="focus"/>
     <sj:datepicker id="idEndDate" name="endDate" displayFormat="dd-mm-yy" showOn="focus" />
</sj:div>
```

And struts.xml code is -

```
<action name="jsonReloadDatePickerAction"  class="com.ebhasin.fitnessbliss.actions.GraphsAction" method="reloadDatePicker">
     <result   type="json" name="success">
        <param name="includeProperties">startDate,endDate</param>
     </result>
</action>
```

I am getting this on JSP page.

```
{"endDate":"18-11-2012","startDate":"07-12-2012"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your datepicker-s to JSP page (e.g. `dates.jsp`) and change your action to return this page instead of json result.

```
<action name="jsonReloadDatePickerAction" class="com.ebhasin.fitnessbliss.actions.GraphsAction" method="reloadDatePicker">
  <result>path_to_your_dates.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Of course you need to have getters/setters for `startDate` and `endDate` in your `GraphsAction` action.